# Giving additional parameters to an ejb call

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

At a project I am working on, we have the need to add some additional parameters to our ejb calls.
We don't put those parameters as regular ejb interface parameters because we already have lots of interfaces and changing most of them would be a pain (plus it's not related to the logic, these are some additional parameters being saved in the database, call it a side effect).

So to the point, we use weblogic as our application server (10.3.4, Java 6, JavaEE 5) and the solution we found for this problem was to make a wrapper ejb that will accept the real method target, its arguments and of course the additional parameters.
The wrapper will then store the additional parameters on the transaction, create a new initial context and lookup the target ejb.

The wrapper ejb function looks like this:

```
public Object invokeWithAdditionalParameters (MethodSignature methodSignature, Object[] args, SomeAdditionalParameter p) {
    transaction.putResource("additionalParam", p);
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
    Object service = ctx.lookup(methodSignature.buildLookupName());
    return methodSignature.getMethod().invoke(service, args);
}
```

MethodSignature holds the targeted ejb method we would like to invoke.

I don't know if this solution is acceptable and if we should cache our InitialContexts, as we are already in the server and don't need to make expensive network calls to the jndi tree, but maybe I'm wrong...

Thank you,
Aviad.

Comment: In theory you should close your `InitialContext` (using try/finally) otherwise you may get some resource leaks in some environments

Comment: You're right, I tried to simplify the example. In reality I have try catch finally statements that eventually closes the context.